# Best approeach in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

i am currently working on a project in which i have to implement a notifications system. I am a really starte with graphs dbs, so i dont know which would be the best approach to implement this. I have been thinking in two options:

1-Creating notifications nodes, relating them to the user with a relation type pending or read. When i insert them i insert them like pending and when the user read them, i change the relation type to read.

2-Creating notifications nodes, relate them to the user and add some property to the relation..."status" (pending,read). Then add an index to that property.

I dont if i am well oriented, i would appreciate if you could point me in what direction.

Thanks in advance. Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo,
it depends a bit on what amount of stuff you are going to expect, and how you are going to ask for this. I think something like

USER---READ--->TODAY---->Status1
  |
  ----UNREAD--->TODAY---->Status2

Would both let you group status for both READ/UNREAD and some property regarding time or otherwise, when a lot of read status are starting to accumulate over time, while still letting you ask traversals over them ...

Would that work?

/peter